# Regex in C# Trying to replace a string that is found using regex between two characters

Tags: c#, regex

I'm attempting to to replace all occurences of a specific name from a paragraph using C#.

Rules:

1. There can be any characters except letters before and after the name.

   - `Hello george how are you` (george is replaced)
   - `Hello georgeman how are you` (george is not replaced)
   - `Hello &^*%(&*^george^&%(^&:. how are you.` (george is replaced)
2. The name can be at the end or the beginning of a paragraph. Ie if the paragraph starts or ends with the name it will be replaced as long as it meets above requirements (basically include the option to have nothing before or after the name).

I was using the regex "\b" currently with ignore case to catch typos as well like "George or george".

C# Code:

```
string name = "george";
string regExString = @"\b"+name+@"\b";
paragraph = Regex.Replace(paragraph, regExString, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

However, I ran into the exception due to shortened names such as "A.J." ; since the `\b` regex includes punctuation as a result it won't match properly placed at the end of the "A.J." name.

I'm looking for a regex that catches my name between spaces and or any characters and only replaces the name. The closest I came up with was checking for punctuation at the end of my string and instead of ending the regExString with a `\b` I would end it with `([^A-Za-z]|$).`

The problem with the regular expression is that it includes the punctuation after; for example using regex:

`\ba.j.([^A-Za-z]|$)`
with the text `A.J.: Hey how are you?`

it would replace `A.J.:` (and I don't want the colon to be replaced).

Comment: You say that letters are A-Z and a-z. Is ß a letter? How about æ? How about ñ? You have a very narrow definition of what makes a letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `(?<!\w)` negative lookbehind instead of the leading word boundary and `(?!\w)` negative lookahead instead of the trailing word boundary to only search words in between non-word chars or start/end of the string:

```
var regExString = $@"(?<!\w){Regex.Escape(name)}(?!\w)";
```

With older C# versions not supporting interpolated string literals, use `string.Format`:

```
var regExString = string.Format(@"(?<!\w){0}(?!\w)", Regex.Escape(name));
```

Note that `Regex.Escape(name)` will escape any special chars if they appear anywhere inside the `name` value.

Here are some variations of custom word boundaries:

- `$@"(?<!\p{{L}}){Regex.Escape(name)}(?!\p{{L}})"` - match a *name* if it is not enclosed with any Unicode letters
- `$@"(?<!\d){Regex.Escape(name)}(?!\d)"` - match a *name* if it is not enclosed with any digits
- `$@"(?<!\S){Regex.Escape(name)}(?!\S)"` - match a *name* only if it is in between whitespace chars or start/end of string.

[C# demo](https://ideone.com/unpqcW):

```
var paragraph = "A.J.: Hey how are you?";
var name = "A.J.";
var regExString = $@"(?<!\w){Regex.Escape(name)}(?!\w)";
paragraph = Regex.Replace(paragraph, regExString, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine(paragraph);
// => : Hey how are you?
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I modified it slightly since the \w was excluding numbers. So the final was this: **(?<![a-zA-Z])Regex.Escape(name)(?![a-zA-Z])**. I understand the expression except for this character: "<". The negative look ahead format is usually: (?!pattern). I was wondering why was "<" included. Thanks again!

Comment: @Traian Use `$@"(?<!\p{{L}}){Regex.Escape(name)}(?!\p{{L}})"` to make sure name is not enclosed with any other Unicode letters. It will make the pattern a bit shorter and more powerful. Well, to only support ASCII, use `$"(?<![a-zA-Z]){Regex.Escape(name)}(?![a-zA-Z])"`

Comment: This was the best choice since it includes unicode characters: **$@"(?<!\p{{L}}){Regex.Escape(name)}(?!\p{{L}})"** . I tried to accept this as the answer but I don't have enough reputation :(